# Result on étaleness of Group schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, group-schemes

I have a question about a proof from Arithmetic Geometry (edited by Cornell & Silverman) on page 51:

[image: esult about]

The proof starts with "According to [6], we may and do assume $S = Spec \ k$, ...

[6] refers to Grothendieck, A. and Dieudonne, J. Elements de geometrie algebrique, IV, No 4.

Unfortunately the author hasn't give the concrete lemma or proposition which justifies this reduction step from $S$ to field. Has anybody an idea which result from EGA 4 on etale schemes the author here have in mind?

Comment: Who is the author amd title of the paper inside the Cornell Silverman book.

Comment: @xarles: the title is "Group Schemes, Formal Groups, and
p-Divisible Groups" by Stephen S. Shatz (starts on page 28; Chapter III)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X\to S$ is an etale morphism of schemes, then the fiber $X_s$ is a disjoint union of spectra of finite separable field extensions of $k(s)$. There is a (partial) converse to this:

**Lemma** (Stacks [02GM](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GM) or EGA IV4 Corollaire 17.6.2): If $X\to S$ is flat, locally of finite presentation, and for every $s\in S$ the fiber $X_s$ is a disjoint union of spectra of finite separable field extensions of $k(s)$, then $X\to S$ is etale.

This is the relevant result.